# Angular - How to implement ngx-switch in Feature Module

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am implementing ngx-bootstrap-switch in Feature module in Angular-13.

based on the documentation I have installed

npm install --save ngx-bootstrap-switch based on the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap-switch)

I have these modules:

AdminModule, SharedModule and the AppModule

Then in the SharedModule, I added this:

```
import { NgxBootstrapSwitchModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap-switch';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    NgxBootstrapSwitchModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Then imported it in the AdminModule where I'm to use it:

```
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  providers: [

  ],
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

admin.component.html:

```
<div class="form-group">

  <ngx-switch [status]="value"
              [onText]="onText"
              [offText]="offText"
              [onColor]="onColor"
              [offColor]="offColor"
              [size]="size"
              [disabled]="disabled"
              (statusChange)="onSwitchChange($event)">
  </ngx-switch>
</div>
```

But I got yhis error:

'ngx-switch' is not a known element:

1. If 'ngx-switch' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-switch' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this comp

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Add shared module inside import array of app.module

Comment: @GRD - I have done that and the problem still not solved.   Please note that admin.component.html is in the AdminModule